# Get json from google analytics

Tags: javascript, json, google-analytics

I've a website with google analytics implemented. Everything shows fine on google analytics page eg. pageviews, gender, age.... but I need to get this data in JSON form for creating my own dashboard on my website. Simply, I need to get age and gender data via the URL link. Something like here:
http://api.opentracker.net/api/trends/trends.jsp?login=demo@opentracker.net&password=demo123&site=www.opentracker.net&period=1d
There is any solution to make this ? 
PS: google analytics is implemented on page X and I'm making the dashboard on page Y. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no webservice specifically designed to export JSON data, but you can use the [Google Analytisc Embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/) to obtain the same results.

For an example, and some open-source code from Google, you might want to check out https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/

Comment: Thanks but it's not the cross-domain solution

Comment: Do you mean that you need to make this Dashboard publicly available?

Comment: I want to get JSON data from page X which have GA implemented on page Y

Comment: I understand. The reason for me asking is that you might risk exposing private API Keys if your Dashboard is intended for public display. You could try using the [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/), and/or the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) to help you format the Query.

Comment: Ye but how can I use it with API secret key ?

Comment: You could use the [Core Reporting API](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1191180?hl=en) to that end. They have great documentation and even easy to follow tutorials: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api

Comment: @DamianMoźniak - if you are looking to create a dashboard and don't want to deal with learning the Core Reporting API, check out http://www.embeddedanalytics.com/embeddedanalytics-reporting-widgets.html

Comment: @PhillipeSawicki Google developer console lets you add credentials so that only certain domains or IPs can use your Client-ID and API-Key.

Answer (score 0):

1º GET YOURAPIKEY - https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started

2º Use link below with your XXXXXX goo.gl short link

> https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?shortUrl=http:// goo.gl/XXXXXX&projection=FULL&key=YOURAPIKEY

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for some time and could not do it so I had done some manual steps that could help people who want to do once in a while - here are the [steps I followed](https://medium.com/@software.wikipedia/how-to-convert-google-analytics-report-to-json-e8d4ce5e0525) -